# How to send a .p7b format client certificate with request in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

I'm fairly new to SSL/TLS. I'm writing a java client that will do a simple get request to a URL. But along with the URL I have to send the client certificate(.p7b) provided to me. I have extracted all the certificates present in the .p7b file to separate .cert file and add those .cert files in the java trust store. However, after doing all the steps when I'm hitting that endpoint I'm getting this warning

```
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

This is the java code I've used for configuring the rest template

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate getTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) throws Exception{
        char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore("classpath:truststore/truststore.jks", password), new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
        return builder
                .requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))
                .build();   
        
    }
    
    private KeyStore keyStore(String file, char[] password) throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        File key = ResourceUtils.getFile(file);
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(key)) {
            keyStore.load(in, password);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyStore;
    }
```

I'm not able to figure out what I have missed. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If by 'send [a] client certificate' you actually mean *do SSL/TLS client authentication*, which the server you tried to connect clearly requested even though you omitted the part of the log that would show it directly, that does NOT consist only of sending the certificate. Sending the certificate does not prove identity, because anybody can copy and send the certificate. To do authentication and prove identity, the SSL/TLS implementation in your system (here the JSSE component of Java) must BOTH send the certificate, along with chain certificate(s) if needed, AND use the corresponding privatekey to sign certain data in the handshake. Some people only notice, and thus only talk about, the first part, but it is useless without the second.

In short, **just sending a certificate is useless** and that means just having the certificate is useless. You must have both the certificate (and usually chain) AND the privatekey, and you apparently don't, because a p7b cannot contain a privatekey.

The normal and recommended procedure is that you get the certs -- possibly but not necessarily as p7b -- from a CA (or from someone who got them from a CA) because you first generated and gave them a CSR (Certificate Signing Request), in which case you already have the privatekey -- find it and use it. The methods for using it depend on what form it is in, which in turn depends on how you generated it, which you didn't say, but you will want to end up with a `KeyStore` object you can give to `.loadKeyMaterial` *NOT* `Trust`. (You only need or should use `.loadTrustMaterial` if the *server* is using a cert under a CA (or anchor) that is not one of the established 'public' CAs.)

If someone else generated the CSR and (then) got the certificate(s), they need to give you the privatekey or you need to get the privatekey from them, and then use it with the cert(s) as above.